# Dynamically add attributes to the local module in Python

Tags: python, module, attributes

If I am to dynamically add attributes to the local module (add attributes within that module), which of the following two ways is preferred and why ? I want to make it work on both Python 2 and 3 as well as future 3.x.

1.

```
# cat ./test1.py
import sys

def set_attr(name, value):
    this = sys.modules[__name__]
    setattr(this, name, value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_attr("get_doubled", lambda x: x * 2)
    set_attr("get_tripled", lambda x: x * 3)
    print(get_doubled(1))
    print(get_tripled(1))
# python ./test1.py
2
3
```

2.

```
# cat ./test2.py
def set_attr(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_attr("get_doubled", lambda x: x * 2)
    set_attr("get_tripled", lambda x: x * 3)
    print(get_doubled(1))
    print(get_tripled(1))
# python ./test2.py
2
3
```

Comment: I think they are equivalent. I cannot think of a scenario in which they would differ. Having said that, I prefer the first one. It feels cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some little difference.  Check this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys

def set_attr(name, value):
    this = sys.modules[__name__]
    setattr(this, name, value)

def set_attr1(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value

def test():
    set_attr("get_doubled", lambda x: x * 2)
    set_attr("get_tripled", lambda x: x * 3)

def test1():
    set_attr1("get_doubled", lambda x: x * 2)
    set_attr1("get_tripled", lambda x: x * 3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit

    print timeit.timeit("test()", "from __main__ import test") # 2.304...
    print timeit.timeit("test1()", "from __main__ import test1")  # 1.201...
```

The complexity must be different. Details should check source code, I think. So, I prefer second way.